# Why is my jQuery Ajax request not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to make a jQuery $.get request work.  I have stripped the code back to its most basic but I still can't understand the problem.

Here is my js:

```
function process_order_meta_changes(item_id) {

alert ("start");

$.get("http://localhost/dropbox/woocommerce_test/wp-content/themes/storefront-child2/process_meta_update.php", 
    function(data){
        alert(data);
    });

alert ("finish");

}
```

And my PHP file

```
<?php

echo "Response from server";

?>
```

The "start" alert works when the function is called, but nothing else happens.  If I open the PHP file in the browser it displays "Response from server", so I know the address is correct.

jQuery is listed as a dependency of the script on enqueing in WordPress and I have checked it has loaded by putting this test in the function:

```
    if (window.jQuery)
    {
        alert ("jQuery is working");
    }
```

I hope someone is able to point out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$` doesn't work straight in WordPress.

You have to use:

```
jQuery.get()
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's `$` shortcut does not work in Wordpress. If it's easier for you to code using it, you could wrap your code with :

```
(function($) {


})( jQuery );
```

Which will alias `jQuery` with `$`.